# Oauth2 process with Google on Ionic 4 is stuck in "please wait"

Tags: oauth-2.0, ionic4

I have a tutorial Ionic 4 application pasted from github.com/ionicthemes/ionic-google-login I have the following code that gets called:

```
this.googlePlus.login({
      'scopes': '', // optional - space-separated list of scopes, If not included or empty, defaults to `profile` and `email`.
      'webClientId': environment.googleWebClientId, // optional - clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
      'offline': true, // Optional, but requires the webClientId - if set to true the plugin will also return a serverAuthCode, which can be used to grant offline access to a non-Google server
    }).then(user => {
      console.log('+++ user is:', user);
    }, err => {
      console.log("+++ google login error:", err);
    })
```

And neither success, nor error messages get printed. I am stick waiting for a response from Google.

I did this: `keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v` and added the sha1 fingerprint on console.developers.google.com. The package name matches (com.tgm_ionic) and I selected oauth2 android flow.

Extra info: This used to work on the browser platform, but would fail on android simulator with error 10, which is "invalid audience." So I created new credentials to move from browser platform to android platform (still oauth2), and now I encounter this issue. The goal here is to be able to login on android, not in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your webClientId is correct. You can reference this in the Google APIs console, then look under credentials and check your OAuth 2.0 client IDs. Often times with these hybrid apps folks are using the android key when the web client ID is needed.

Comment: <integer>-<hash>.apps.googleusercontent.com and the reverse of it, are correct.

Comment: Are you sure it is the one for the web client and not android?